# How to include colors for CKEditor's table configuration select?

Tags: ckeditor

I need to make a change to the color list of the dialog that is used to change the color of the table cells in CKEditor. Does anyone know how to change?

Answer (score 0):

Cell Properties dialog uses Color Dialog plugin:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/tabletools/dialogs/tableCell.js#L15
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/tabletools/dialogs/tableCell.js#L380

The Color Dialog doesn't have configuration property to set up colors. They are being created in one huge private method:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/colordialog/dialogs/colordialog.js#L207-L268

You would probably need to fork CKEditor repository, make changes in that method and then build your own release of the editor if you want to add colors. Please see:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_source.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_build.html